# Bundle dependencies in a library or externalize them

Tags: javascript, npm, vite, rollupjs

We are working on a Vue library which contains common components and common modules that we use to build Vue apps.

We are using Vue 3, Vite and npm.

Now that the library is growing in size we would like to optimize dependencies that we both use in the library and in the app (e.g: Bootstrap, and let's limit this example to the js code, no CSS). The goal is to avoid bundling them twice: once in the library, once in the app.
However I see two approach to solve this:

#### Bundle dependencies in the library and export them as modules

In the library (where bootstrap is a dependency of `package.json`):

```js
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
//...
export {bootstrap};
```

And then we import it in the app:

```js
import { bootstrap } from "my-lib";
```

This way I am sure I will share the same version of Bootstrap between the library and the app. However the dependency to Bootstrap will not appear in the `package.json` of the app and the bundled size of the lib will be bigger.

#### Externalize dependencies in the library

In the library `vite.config.js` :

```js
rollupOptions: {
  external: ['vue', 'bootstrap'],
  // ...
}
```

In the library `package.json`:

```js
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "5.3.x"
  },
  // I still need bootstrap as a devDependencies for the dev mode of the lib
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0"
  }
}
```

I guess I have to add Bootstrap as a `peerDependencies` here to be sure that it is installed in the app when we install the library.

This seems like the usual way to do, however it feels more complicated to synchronize the version of Bootstrap between the app and the lib. Indeed I have to be very careful about the version I put in this `peerDependencies`.
The size of the lib will be lower but the total size app + lib will remain the same.

#### Finally, the question is...

Are both ways correct? Why does it seem that externalizing dependencies is generally more preferred whereas it raises this question of version mismatch between app and lib?